# Create new tag for images in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I want add a new label for `<img>` html element like this:

[image]

Is there some JS plugin to do this o something similar in CSS ?

Comment: are you tried anything

Comment: Question is unclear. Do you want to dynamically insert images using JS? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Do you want to add a layer to an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not found plugins to do that, but you can do it from scratch, take a look at this tutorial http://www.inserthtml.com/2012/03/creating-css-image-ribbons/

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this using css

```css
#par {
  position: relative;
}
#par img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
#tri {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 100px solid red;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
}
#tri:before {
  content: 'New';
  position: absolute;
  left: 23px;
  top: -68px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="par">
  <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/01/23/16/02/experimental-1157660_960_720.png" />
  <div id="tri"></div>
</div>
```

**[For more css shapes take a look at here](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)**